# Python Matplotlib pyplot - x axis values unfitting for data

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

(Using python 3.5 x64 for windows)

Hi there!

Im using data in the format of an integer at a specific unix time.
I have a problem where I want the x-axis (unix time) to be "time since first record in seconds" but the values of this axis are not fitting this. I mean: The first integer from the y axis is not set at the 0 value of the x axis.
How can I change the values of the x axis to fit my needs?
I tried several things already: xticks, axes.set_ylim()...but always ran into a problem that i couldnt resolve. xticks could work, but i dont know how to fit the unix time in that so that the correlation between cpm and time does not get lost...

```
def plot_overview2(selector = None):
global logtime, logtime_delta, cpm, color

plt.figure(figsize=(14,7), dpi=70, facecolor="none")     #was figsize=(20,10),dpi=70,facecolor="none" - filled whole screen
plt.suptitle('CPM ', fontsize=16, fontweight='bold')
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=None, wspace=.2, left=.05, top=.95, bottom=.07, right=.98)
plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
plt.grid(True)

# add a label to the x and y axis
plt.xlabel('Time since first record [sec]')      
plt.ylabel("CPM")

# define the x-axis limits
xmin = logtime.min() # e.g. 1483049960.0
xmax = logtime.max() # e.g. 1483295877.0
plt.xlim(xmin, xmax) # if commented out then the plot will find its own limits
#plt.xticks(1, logtime_delta)

# define the y-axis limits
#plt.ylim(0, 150)    # if commented out then the plot will find its own limits

recmax = cpm.size       # allows to limit the data range plotted
# plot the raw data
plt.plot(logtime[:recmax],cpm[:recmax], color=color['cpm'], linewidth=.75, label ="") #linewidth was .5, logtime[:recmax],cpm[:recmax]
#plt.plot_date(logtime, cpm, color=color['cpm'], linewidth=.75, label ="")

# plot the moving average over N datapoints with red on yellow line background
# skip the first and last N/2 data points, which are meaningless due to averaging
if len(logtime) < 300:
    N=len(logtime)+1/2
else:
    N=300
plt.plot(logtime[N//2:recmax - N//2], np.convolve(cpm, np.ones((N,))/N, mode='same')[N//2:recmax - N//2], color="yellow", linewidth=6, label ="")
plt.plot(logtime[N//2:recmax - N//2], np.convolve(cpm, np.ones((N,))/N, mode='same')[N//2:recmax - N//2], color="red",    linewidth=2, label ="MovAvg, N="+str(N))

# plot the line for the average
av      = np.empty(recmax)
npav    = np.average(cpm[:recmax])
av[:]   = npav
plt.plot(logtime[:recmax], av[:recmax], color=color['MW'], linewidth=2, label= "Average CPM={0:6.3f}".format(npav))

# plot the legend in the upper left corner 
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, .9), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
```

Im really new to python. So could you please give easy answers. :)
Thank you!

First plotted line starts at almost 20000

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could maybe subtract the offset when you plot, something like this:

```
plot(logtime[N//2:recmax - N//2] - logtime[0], ...
```

for all of the plots.

Comment: Ok that worked and was suprisingly easy... xD Thank you!